# PHP JSON-RPC not working - no errors

Tags: php, json, json-rpc

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
        require_once '/var/www/jsonrpcphp/includes/jsonRPCClient.php';
        $dogecoind = new jsonRPCClient('http://dogecoinrpc:password@127.0.0.1:8832/');

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        }



        echo '<p>';
        $cusaddress = $dogecoind->getnewaddress();
        echo $cusaddress . " CURRENTLY NOT WORKING   -- this is your PERSONAL deposit address";
        echo "<p> Try a small amount of doge initially to ensure everything is setup correctly </p>";
        echo "<p>It works by generating a number between 0 and 65535, if it's lower than 32767 you win 1.98x payout on your initial investment!";
        echo "<p>If you lose, you will be sent 0.01 as confirmation of your loss.";
        echo '</p>';
        echo "<p> It shouldn't take longer than 5 minutes to get a reply </p>";
        $towritecsv =array($cusaddress, $address);


$line = "\"" . $towritecsv[0] . "\"" . "," . "\"" . $towritecsv[1]  . "\"" . "\n";

$f = fopen("addresses.csv", "a" );
fwrite ( $f, $line);
fclose($f);



?>
</body>
```

Here's what I know it's not doing:
It's processing upto this line

```
$cusaddress = $dogecoind->getnewaddress();
```

Which is where it gets stuck and doesn't echo anything below it.

I just moved the code from a vm to a dedicated machine when it stopped working AND I HAVE NO IDEA WHY.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to check error logs?

Comment: I get no errors printed out, where else could I find them?

Comment: It depends on your system and webserver (e.g. default on linux/apache they are in /var/log/apache/), also you can try to check if there is "display_errors = On" in php.ini.